# Is it possible to store setTimeout function inside a localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, settimeout

Provided that I have the javascript code below.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                alert('this is executed after 5 seconds');
              }, 5000);

localStorage.setItem('timeout_event', timeout);
```

I have checked the return value of the setTimeout function to be an id or something. If the user refreshes the page, how do I re-run the timeout event? Is it even possible?

Any help will do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check what the value of `timeout` is. It's just an integer ID of the timer that you can pass into `clearTimeout`.

Comment: `setTimeout` returns an ID of the timer, and it will reset each time the browser is reopened.

Answer (score 3):

> I have checked the return value of the `setTimeout` function to be an id or something.

Yes, it is a numeric id which you can pass to `clearTimeout` for cancelling a scheduled function run.

> If the user refreshes the page, how do I re-run the timeout event?

Yes, when the page is unloaded all outstanding timeouts are aborted, so you'll need to restart the timeout on the new page.

> Is it even possible?

Yes and no. You won't be able to run the function which you scheduled from the last page - all its context/scope would be lost - you need to create a new one, in the context of the new page.

But if you want to execute certain functionalities based on a timeout/interval across pages, you can do so by using [DOM storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) or similar. You would store the timestamp of the designated function run, and a flag whether it has already run. That way, you can check on following pages whether and when you need to re-schedule the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your timeout function to be executed whenever the page is refreshed , you just add the function in `window.onload`

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                alert('this is executed after 5 seconds');
              }, 5000);

window.onload = timeout;
```

This works fine for me

If you want it to be executed for multiple times , then go for [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
var timeout = setInterval(function(){
                alert('this is executed for each second');
              }, 1000);

window.onload = timeout;
```

It will be executed until you call `clearInterval(timeout);`

If you want multiple timeouts then you should do something like this

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                alert('this is executed after 1 second');
              }, 1000);

var timeout1 = setTimeout(function(){
                alert('this is executed after 2 seconds');
              }, 2000);

var timeout2 = setTimeout(function(){
                alert('this is executed after 3 seconds');
              }, 3000);
window.onload = timeout;timeout1;timeout2;
```

This is because setTimeout calculates the time as soon as the page is refreshed and this works fine for me

Comment: is there any way we can run multiple timeout variables?

Comment: Oh..what i meant was...create multiple setTimeout functions with different commands..and then execute them all during refresh.

Comment: See my edited answer to have multiple timeout functions during page load

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help guys.

I managed to find a way to solve the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timeout_time = 10;
        var time_remaining = 0;

        if(localStorage.getItem('timeout_time')==null){
            run_timeout(timeout_time);
        }
        else{
            run_timeout(localStorage.getItem('timeout_time'))
        }

        setInterval(function(){
            time_remaining = localStorage.getItem('timeout_time');

            if(time_remaining > 1 || time_remaining != null){
                localStorage.setItem('timeout_time', time_remaining - 1);
            }
        }, 1000);

        function run_timeout(time){
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert('executed on 10 seconds');
                localStorage.removeItem('timeout_time');
            }, time * 1000);
            localStorage.setItem('timeout_time', time);
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    This is the test page.
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this can be useful for others.

Again, thank you all.